# spring-simple-memcache - maven dependencies for ReadThroughSingleCache

Tags: spring, memcached, simple-spring-memcached, ssm

Has anyone used spring simple memcached? I have not been able to get the exact maven dependency and the repository where this is available. 
The dependencies mentioned on the code.google page (http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/) mention other dependencies but it does not include jar for Simple-spring-memcache itself.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You need to accept some answers. Out of 7 questions you have no accepted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of SSM 2.0.0 you need also memcached client (xmemcached or spymemcached):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-spring-memcached</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.xmemcached</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmemcached</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and configure connection to local memcached server:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="simplesm-context.xml" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean name="defaultMemcachedClient" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
          <property name="cacheClientFactory">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
          </property>
          <property name="addressProvider">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
                     <property name="address" value="127.0.0.1:11211" />
                </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="configuration">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
                      <property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
                </bean>
          </property>
     </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks ragnor. Looks like you have updated the page now? Thanks for the elaborate documentation on the page as well.

Comment: The documentation is still under construction. I'm going to improve it. Feel free to ask questions on simple-spring-memcached mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/simple-spring-memecached where you can get fast answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-spring-memcached</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```